# Node.js can't send headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm attempting to make a small app that scrapes the 500px.com (a photo site) rss feed for a given user's photo thumbs. I'm relatively new to all this.

I'm seeing a behavior I don't understand when testing locally. The page loads fine the first time, but when reloading, I'm getting "can't send headers after they are sent." From other answers here, it seems this is commonly caused by double-callbacks. I've tried putting some `if (err) res.send();` statements in various places, but it doesn't seem to have solved the problem. I've also tried reconfiguring the code's structure, which also doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone more experienced than me spot what's going on here?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var body = new EventEmitter();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {


  request("https://500px.com/janedoe/rss", function(error, response, data) {
        body.data = data;
        body.emit('update');
  }); 

  body.on('update', function() {

    parseString(body.data, function (err, result) {

        // the stuff below likely isn't relevant to the problem, just some testing

        var photoLink = result.rss.channel[0].item[0].description[0];

        const $ = cheerio.load(photoLink);
        const links = $('img');
        const linkString = links.attr('src').toString();

        // end of area probably not relevant

        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', linkString});

    });



  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: where it is imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.  What is likely causing the specific error you ask about is that each time your route is hit, you add another listener to your EventEmitter object so after the second time the route is hit, you have two listeners and thus when you emit, you have two listeners that get called and you try to send two responses, one of which to an older response object that has already sent its response.

The core issue here is that you're trying to use a module level variable inside a request.  That causes cross coupling between different requests (that are both trying to potentially use the same emitter object while processing their requests).  This is just a race condition waiting to happen as soon as you have more than one user using your system.

I have no idea why you're using an `EventEmitter` object here at all since it doesn't appear you need one.  You could just process your final result when the request has gather all its data and not use an EventEmitter at all.  This would fix the race condition and the multiple handlers.

Here's one approach to fixing:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    request("https://500px.com/janedoe/rss", function(error, response, data) {
        if (error) {
            next(error);
            return;
        }
        parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            // the stuff below likely isn't relevant to the problem, just some testing

            var photoLink = result.rss.channel[0].item[0].description[0];

            const $ = cheerio.load(photoLink);
            const links = $('img');
            const linkString = links.attr('src').toString();

            // end of area probably not relevant

            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Express',
                linkString
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Summary of changes:

1. Move `parseString()` operation inside of `request()` callback.
2. Get rid of shared EventEmitter usage entirely.
3. Add error handling on both async operations.

---

If, for some reason, you needed or wanted to use an `EventEmitter` in your code (though the current code does not show why you would need to use one), you have to create a new one for each request you are processing and only store it within the scope of that particular request (not in a module level variable).  That both prevents cross talk between separate requests in flight and prevents adding more than one listener for the same event to your `EventEmitter` object because there's a separate `EventEmitter` for each request and you only add one listener to that `EventEmitter` object.  Here's how that could work:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // make EventEmitter object for this particular request
    let body = new EventEmitter();

    request("https://500px.com/janedoe/rss", function(error, response, data) {
        if (error) {
            next(error);
            return;
        }
        body.data = data;
        body.emit('update');
    });

    body.on('update', function() {

        parseString(body.data, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }

            // the stuff below likely isn't relevant to the problem, just some testing

            var photoLink = result.rss.channel[0].item[0].description[0];

            const $ = cheerio.load(photoLink);
            const links = $('img');
            const linkString = links.attr('src').toString();

            // end of area probably not relevant

            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Express',
                linkString
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the explanation. So essentially each time a client loads the page, it cues up a new EventEmitter instance -- and thus when the update rolls in, it's trying to render twice or more times for the same client, which it can't do?

Comment: @testingtesting - Not exactly.  Your code only has one EventEmitter instance, but each the time the client loads a page, you add another listener on that one instance.  Then when you `.emit()` to it, all the listeners fire, causing it to send multiple responses, thus triggering the log message you see.  Plus, you also have a vulnerability because you are sharing a single `EventEmitter` with all request handlers so any time your server is serving multiple users, you are vulnerable to cross talk / race conditions between different users.

Comment: @testingtesting - I added an example of how you could safely use an `EventEmitter` in your code by creating a new `EventEmitter` object for each request.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could move everything in `body.on('update...` into the call back for the request.  You should also have error handling in the case that the request fails.  I don't know what the rest of the app looks like but the EventsEmitter isn't necessary here.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var body = new EventEmitter();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request("https://500px.com/janedoe/rss", function(error, response, data) {
    parseString(data, function (err, result) {

      // the stuff below likely isn't relevant to the problem, just some testing

      var photoLink = result.rss.channel[0].item[0].description[0];

      const $ = cheerio.load(photoLink);
      const links = $('img');
      const linkString = links.attr('src').toString();

      // end of area probably not relevant

      res.render('index', { title: 'Express', linkString});

    });
  }); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: @jfriend00 does a great job of explaining the why in his answer

Comment: Yep, I think I'm getting a handle on why this was the wrong approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `EventEmitter` inside your route handler to avoid this.

Simply cut this line:

```
var body = new EventEmitter();
```

and paste it inside your route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var body = new EventEmitter();          // Paste it here
  request("https://500px.com/janedoe/rss", function(error, response, data) {
        body.data = data;
        body.emit('update');
  }); 

  // The rest of your code here ...

});
```

Comment: Got it, interesting. So actually the problem was that I was trying to perform numerous updates on the same EventEmitter instance, if I'm understanding this correctly.